# Changing tab bar font in Swift

Tags: swift, uitabbar, uifont

I have been trying to change the font for the tab bar items however I haven't been able to find any Swift examples. I know that this is how you change it in Objective-C:

```
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIFont fontWithName:@"AmericanTypewriter" size:20.0f], UITextAttributeFont, nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

But how can I translate this into Swift?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The UITextAttributeFont was deprecated in iOS 7. You should use the NS variant instead:

```
import UIKit

let appearance = UITabBarItem.appearance()
let attributes = [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "American Typewriter", size: 20)]
appearance.setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, forState: .Normal)
```

Comment: Nevermind, I put the code in awakeFromNib and that fixed it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Note: using Playground is a great way of finding this kind of thing out. You can also have a look at http://swifter.natecook.com to find out some of the names.

Comment: As of XCode 6.1 this does not seem to work. I am getting a 'NSString' is not identical to 'NSObject'. Does this happen to you guys as well?

Comment: As of 6.1 you must unwrap the font. Just put ! after your the font init

Comment: if you find the increased text size messes up your tabs, with overlapping etc. In interface builder, select your tab bar and change item positioning to fill, rather than automatic.

Comment: `UISegmentedControl` docs still reference the deprecated values :( How did you find out about the new values?

Comment: This doesn't change font for me for `.selected` state.

Answer (score 62):

**Swift 4.2**

```
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "FontName", size: 10)!], for: .normal)
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "FontName", size: 10)!], for: .selected)
```

**Swift 4**

```
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "FontName", size: 10)!], for: .normal)
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "FontName", size: 10)!], for: .selected)
```

**Swift 3**

```
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Font-Name", size: 10)!], for: .normal)
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Font-Name", size: 10)!], for: .selected)
```

**Note:**  Use `setTitleTextAttributes` for both `.normal` and `.selected` to have changes persist selection state changes.

Comment: This doesn't change font for me for `.selected` state.

Comment: @AbbasAngouti - you just need to duplicate the code and change `.normal` to `.selected`

Comment: Where should I put this piece of o code? Should I create a class for the TabBarController or?

Comment: can confirm it doesn't work for selected

Answer (score 11):

Put this under `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
UITabBarItem.appearance()
    .setTitleTextAttributes(
        [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "Didot", size: 10)!], 
    for: .normal)
```

This works in Swift 4

Comment: for me calling this method on UITabBarItem.appearance() didn't work. Had to replace it with self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?

Answer (score 8):

**Swift 5**

```
let appearance = UITabBarItem.appearance()
let attributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font:UIFont(name: "American Typewriter", size: 20)]
appearance.setTitleTextAttributes(attributes as [NSAttributedString.Key : Any], for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 4):

In addition @Mc.Lover 's answer, If you want to aplly this change to all of your tab bar Items in application, I recommand to add the code in `application` function of AppDelegate class:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    //Just add this line to get it done.       
    UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "IranSansMobile", size: 15)!], for: UIControlState.normal)

    return true
}
```

Answer (score 4):

One more Answer, but for `iOS 15`:

```
if #available(iOS 15, *) {
    let tabBarAppearance = UITabBarAppearance()
    tabBarAppearance.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
    tabBarAppearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.selected.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: selectedItemTextColor, .font: UIFont(name: "American Typewriter", size: 20)]
    tabBarAppearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: unselectedItemTextColor, .font: UIFont(name: "American Typewriter", size: 20)]
    tabBar.standardAppearance = tabBarAppearance
    tabBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = tabBarAppearance
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Swift 4.2

```
    UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "BahijTheSansArabic-Plain", size: 10)!], for: .normal)
    UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "BahijTheSansArabic-Plain", size: 10)!], for: .selected)
```

Comment: @bibscy in AppDelegate.swift inside func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool { 

}

Answer (score 2):

In Swift4 version, you can use attribute keys to set font and foreground color

```
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor(hexString: "#D8FFE8"), NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 16) as Any], for: .normal)
    UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor(hexString: "#FFFFFF"),NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 16) as Any], for: .selected)
```

Comment: Doesn't work for selected