# Setting UITabBarItem attributed text does not work

Tags: swift

I want to change the text style, font and colours, for the tab bar. I have tried the appearance proxy approach in `AppDelegate` but it didn't work, then I tried to call `setTitleTextAttributes()` on every `UITabBarItem` individually, it didn't work either. I'm frustrated (iOS 13)!

```
let appearance = UITabBarItem.appearance()

appearance.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.red], for: .normal)

appearance.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.green], for: .selected)
```

*Above does not work*

The only thing that worked, sort of, to change the default colours was setting the tint colour via `UITabBar` appearance proxy in `AppDelegate`:

```
UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.black
```

I cannot change the font with this. Has it changed in iOS13? I could not find anything about it in Appel docs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing tab bar font in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26069334/changing-tab-bar-font-in-swift)

Comment: It's a bug. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/58944991/341994.

Comment: @matt apparently it's a bug then, thanks.